# How do I properly add transitions to D3 Polygons?

Tags: d3.js, polygon, transition, polygons

**Original Code can be found at:** http://bl.ocks.org/Guerino1/451f4c47842967dd813c8a64b24f7686

**Problem:** Applying .transition() code to different polygon sets appears to yield different results.

The following portion of the code seems to work as expected.  Applying a transition causes the chevrons to transition onto the svg canvas, from left to right...

```
    svgChevronsCanvas.selectAll("a")
        .data(dataSet)
      .enter().append("a")
        .attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return d.link; })
      .append("svg:polygon")
        .attr("id", function(d,i){ return ("chevron_" + selectString.replace(/ /g,'_').replace(/#/g,'') + "_index_" + i); })
        .attr("originalcolor", polygonPrimaryColor)
        //.style("stroke","blue")
        //.style("stroke-width",1)
        .style("fill", polygonPrimaryColor)
        .attr("points", chevronOrigin)
        .on('mouseover', chevronMouseOver)
        .on("mouseout", chevronMouseOut)
        .on("click", chevronMouseOut)
        .transition() // <------------------- TRANSITION HERE
        .duration(3000)
        .attr("points", calculateChevron);
```

The following code, which attempts to follow the same pattern as above does not seem to work as expected.  Given the transition, I would expect the textboxes (in light blue below the chevrons), which are also drawn using D3 polygons, to transition onto their svg canvas from left to right, just like the chevron polygons in the above code...

```
    svgTextboxesCanvas.selectAll("a")
        .data(dataSet)
      .enter().append("a")
        .attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return d.link; })
      .append("svg:polygon")
        .attr("id", function(d,i){ return ("textbox_" + selectString.replace(/ /g,'_').replace(/#/g,'') + "_index_" + i); })
        .attr("originalcolor", textboxColor)
        .style("stroke", textboxColor)
        .style("stroke-width",1)
        .style("fill", textboxColor)
        .attr("points", textboxesOrigin)
        .on('mouseover', textboxMouseOver)
        .on("mouseout", textboxMouseOut)
        .on("click", textboxMouseOut)
        .transition()
        .duration(3000)
        .attr("points", calculateTextbox);
```

**Question:** How do I properly add transitions to the D3 polygons that are built to look like rectangles (below the chevrons), in the latter set of code, and make them transition into the page just like the dark blue chevrons above them?

Answer (score 0):

In the original [code](http://bl.ocks.org/Guerino1/451f4c47842967dd813c8a64b24f7686):

Make

```
var chevronGapSpace = 5;//this is the distance between each rectangle.
var slantDepth = 0;//to make the polygon rectangle.
```

Next, to make rectangle transition inside function `calculateChevron` change the calculations accordingly:

```
function calculateChevron(d, i){
  return [
    [(svgMargin) + i*(chevronDistance),chevronTopOffset],
    [(svgMargin + chevronWidth - slantDepth) + i*(chevronDistance),chevronTop],
    [(svgMargin + chevronWidth - slantDepth) + i*(chevronDistance),chevronPointY],
    [(svgMargin + chevronWidth - slantDepth) + i*(chevronDistance),chevronBottom],
    [(svgMargin) + i*(chevronDistance),chevronBottom],
    [(svgMargin + slantDepth) + i*(chevronDistance),chevronPointY]
  ];
};
```

working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/9t7dkA0L3eD3RRsbTM2D?p=preview)

Comment: Hi Cyril, thanks for trying but this does not address the problem.  The problem is that the rectangles "below" the chevrons are not transitioning into the canvas like the chevrons above them.

Comment: Sorry! not clear...what do you mean by canvas? there is no canvas here. Its only SVG! Moreover in your question you have not given a fiddle so how can  someone guess the rectangle you using...I hope you understand what i am trying to say.